# Does the D garbage collector work?

Tags: garbage-collection, d

So I tried to test whether the D garbage collector works properly by running this program on Windows.

DMD 2.057 and 2.058 beta both give the same result, whether or not I specify `-release`, `-inline`, `-O`, etc.

The code:

```
import core.memory, std.stdio;

extern(Windows) int GlobalMemoryStatusEx(ref MEMORYSTATUSEX lpBuffer);

struct MEMORYSTATUSEX
{
    uint Length, MemoryLoad;
    ulong TotalPhys, AvailPhys, TotalPageFile, AvailPageFile;
    ulong TotalVirtual, AvailVirtual, AvailExtendedVirtual;
}

void testA(size_t count)
{
    size_t[] a;
    foreach (i; 0 .. count)
        a ~= i;
    //delete a;
}

void main()
{
    MEMORYSTATUSEX ms;
    ms.Length = ms.sizeof;

    foreach (i; 0 .. 32)
    {
        testA(16 << 20);
        GlobalMemoryStatusEx(ms);
        stderr.writefln("AvailPhys: %s MiB", ms.AvailPhys >>> 20);
    }
}
```

The output was:

```
AvailPhys: 3711 MiB
AvailPhys: 3365 MiB
AvailPhys: 3061 MiB
AvailPhys: 2747 MiB
AvailPhys: 2458 MiB
core.exception.OutOfMemoryError
```

When I uncommented the `delete a;` statement, the output was

```
AvailPhys: 3714 MiB
AvailPhys: 3702 MiB
AvailPhys: 3701 MiB
AvailPhys: 3702 MiB
AvailPhys: 3702 MiB
...
```

So I guess the question is obvious... does the GC actually work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a regression - it doesn't happen in D1 (DMD 1.069). David Simcha has been optimizing the GC lately, so it might have something to do with that. Please file a bug report.

Comment: ... whoa. So it's been broken in D2 entirely?

Comment: No, of course not - I bet you just hit a corner case or something.

Comment: Funny, it's quite literally the first thing I tried to explicitly test the GC.

Answer (score 8):

The problem here is false pointers.  D's garbage collector is conservative, meaning it doesn't always know what's a pointer and what isn't.  It sometimes has to assume that bit patterns that would point into GC-allocated memory if interpreted as pointers, are pointers.  This is mostly a problem for large allocations, since large blocks are a bigger target for false pointers.

You're allocating about 48 MB each time you call `testA()`.  In my experience this is enough to almost guarantee there will be a false pointer into the block on a 32-bit system.  You'll probably get better results if you compile your code in 64-bit mode (supported on Linux, OSX and FreeBSD but not Windows yet) since 64-bit address space is much more sparse.

As far as my GC optimizations (I'm the David Simcha that CyberShadow mentions) there were two batches.  One's been in for >6 months and hasn't caused any problems.  The other is still in review as a pull request and isn't in the main druntime tree yet.  These probably aren't the problem.

Short term, the solution is to manually free these huge blocks.  Long term, we need to add precise scanning, at least for the heap.  (Precise stack scanning is a much harder problem.)  I wrote a patch to do this a couple years ago but it was rejected because it relied on templates and compile time function evaluation to generate pointer offset information for each datatype.  Hopefully this information will eventually be generated directly by the compiler and I can re-create my precise heap scanning patch for the garbage collector.

Comment: Are you *sure* that's the actual problem though? For one thing, the pointers aren't random -- they span the lower 16 MiB of virtual memory (from address 0 to address 16 << 20). I'm pretty sure there's nothing in that region of virtual memory -- and even if there was (?!), that would only prevent *one* of the arrays from being collected (since each one is > 16 MiB), not the *entire* array. And, aside from that, shouldn't the GC be ignoring the `size_t` blocks in the first place? I thought it would only scan data that could contain pointers (`NO_SCAN`)?

Comment: @Mehrdad:  Two things:  One, the false pointers aren't coming **from** the blocks you're allocating.  They're coming from static data, the stack, RTTI, etc.  Two, the GC doesn't start allocating using the lowest addresses.  It starts at some arbitrary address higher up.  (I don't know the details.)  Try just allocating 48 MB in a loop using something like new byte[48 * 1024 * 1024].  I bet that would run out of memory or at least use a huge amount, too, though it would take longer.

Comment: Do you happen to know by any chance why [the issue](http://d.puremagic.com/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=7251) is marked as `Resolved Invalid`?

Answer (score 2):

P.S. If you rebuild Druntime with DFLAGS set to `-debug=PRINTF` in the makefile, you will get information on when the GC allocates/deallocates via console. :)

Answer (score 1):

It does work. Current implementation just never releases memory to operating system. Though GC reuses acquired memory, so it's not a really a leak.

Comment: So what was the deal with the `core.exception.OutOfMemoryError` that got thrown? And how was memory returned to the OS when I said `delete`?

Comment: Perl never releases memory back to the operating system either, and it's been around for more than two decades.

Comment: @BradGilbert: I can't tell what you were trying to say, but it's good to know I guess..

Comment: @Mehrdad Just saying that it doesn't matter a whole lot that it doesn't *currently* return the memory back to the OS. With modern OS memory handlers, it doesn't matter all that much anyway.